# Installing requests library to a target folder

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the requests library to a target folder but I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe:
No module named install.__main__; 'install' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

What does this mean and how do I resolve it?

Comment: can you paste the command line to install?

Comment: You can check how many versions of pip you have installed with wich pip

Comment: did you even install pip ?

Comment: I used py -m pip install target="d:\my\directory" requests

Comment: pip version is: pip 21.1.3 from C:\Users\myUserDirectory\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: I seem to have pip installed in 2 different locations - could tht be cause of my issue?

Answer (score 0):

my issue was caused by the syntax I was using.  The syntax that worked for me is:

pip install requests -t C:\Users\YourUserName\Documents\AWS\LambdaSourceCode